# Core Data Managed Object Context Saving Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, saving-data

I am trying to save an array into core data using NSData but my ManagedObjectContext says there are 0 objects and when I call it, I have it appearing as NULL. I have an entity called Event and 3 attributes in it (chatArray,...,...). I have tried for 11 hours and can't figure it out. I believe I am setting it wrong because the NSData is correct. How should I be setting this???

UPDATE

I am developing a chat application and I have the chat messages in a table view (It's an array of data). I need to save all the chat history when you exit the app and reload it. I have the messages coming in as strings and add it to the array for the table. If I didn't do an array, and I added the messages as strings of text to core data how would I add them to the array for the table view when you reload the app?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *managedObject;
```

//

```
NSArray *array = [[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three", nil]autorelease];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
NSLog(@"data %@",data);

NSLog(@"Array %@",[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]);

[(Event*)managedObject setValue:data forKey:@"chatArray"];

if ([self managedObject])
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    [(Event *)managedObject setChatArray:data];              }
else {
    Event *event = [[[Event alloc] initInsertingIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]autorelease];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    [event setChatArray:data];
}

NSError *error;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];

NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[(Event*)managedObject valueForKey:@"chatArray"]];

NSLog(@"chatArray %@",myArray);
```

Comment: I can't really tell what's supposed to happen here. You have managedObject and [self managedObject]. Am I right in assuming those are the same thing? But you send a message to it before you check it it's nil. What happens then? If it's not nil, it won't run any code that inserts into your model. So if you inserted managedObject into your model before or not, I don't know. You create a fetch request in both cases but you don't ever execute it. What code path is it taking? Did you check the value of error after you save the context?

Comment: It takes the second one. And it has no error its Nill though...

Answer (score 1):

Brandon,

First, in Core Data, BLOBs should be stored in leaf nodes (i.e. an entity that just contains the BLOB and a back to one relationship. (This pattern/convention has emerged because it is almost trivial to get a retain cycle of large blobs when there are other relations in the entity.)

Second, why are you storing these strings as an array and not as an entity with a time stamp, etc.?A BLOB is not particularly more efficient than individual rows plus the system can both search the messages and more flexibly store the rows. SQLite handles strings specially.

Third, it appears that you are composing your class rather than inheriting from your model entity, why? This makes your code more complex.

Finally, It is really hard to tell what you are trying to do. Could you include your full .h file? And the full method declaration?

Andrew

Comment: I am developing a chat application and I have the chat messages in a table view (It's an array of data). I need to save all the chat history when you exit the app and reload it. I have the messages coming in as strings and add it to the array for the table. If I didn't do an array, and I added the messages as strings of text to core data how would I add them to the array for the table view when you reload the app?

Comment: Brandon, the NSFetchedResultsController is specifically designed to fetch an array from a Core Data model and interface in a natural way with a UITableView. IOW, it solves the problem you have. Andrew